# How to slow down an in browser test cucumber on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, cucumber

I'm trying to find a way in which I can slow my tests down when running in-browser tests in cucumber.

I'm using selenium within cucumber - ruby rails.

When I run the tests, the steps are happening so quick you can't take in what's going on.

So short of adding a line of "sleep 2" in the code for every step. i.e:

```
When /^I fill in my name$/ do |name|
  sleep 2
   fill_in('name', :with => name)
end
```

I'm looking for one line of code that will have the same effect.

This line exists in my env.rb file but doesn't do anything:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
  AfterStep do
    sleep (ENV['PAUSE'] || 0).to_i
  end
```

I've tried changing the 0 to a higher value and still nothing.

I'm pretty new to this and any help would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have a hooks.rb file in features/support.  I guess that is standard.  I put in

```
AfterStep do
  sleep 2
end
```

And it kind of worked.  It doesn't pause within a step that does a bunch of things, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
After do
  sleep 2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set default wait time for capybara to render the page:

```
Capybara.default_wait_time = 5
```

now whenever you use (find) or some others method that wait for the default wait time, it will wait 5 second if the element doesn't render and if the element renders before that it will continue without waiting 5 sec, so before your fill_in code use something like:

```
   page.should have_selector('your drowndown id or locator')
   or
   find('your drowndown id or locator')
   fill_in('name', :with => name)
```

so now it won't get to the fill_in step untill the dropdown renders other wise it will wait
5 sec and you can increase that time.